# Why does React's useReducer returns an empty state when the data is present the first time it was fetched on useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I'm working on a simple MERN stack todo app using react hooks and **contextAPI**, I fetch the data from mongodb database using axios and set the **initialState** array variable with **useEffect** to simulate **componentDidMount**, then the **initialState** is used as a parameter to the **useReducer**. My problem is the child component doesn't received the **initialState** but an empty array, however all other props such as disptach and loading variables get through. Why does the useReducer returns and empty state array?

Parent Component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useReducer } from 'react';
import Header from './components/header/Header';
import Main from './components/main/Main';
import AppContext from './context/AppContext';
import axios from 'axios';
import './stylesheets/index.scss';

function App() {
  const [initialState, setInitialState] = useState([]);
  const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  /* Fetch data */
  const fetchData = async () => {
    setIsError(false);
    setIsLoading(true);
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('/list');
      setInitialState(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      setIsError(true);
      console.log(`Unable to get: ${error}`);
    }
    setIsLoading(false);
  };

  /* Post new data */
  const postNewData = async (parameter) => {
    setIsError(false);
    try {
      const response = await axios.post('/list', parameter);
      console(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      setIsError(true);
      console.log(`Unable to post: ${error}`);
    }
  };

  /* Delete data */
  const deleteData = async (id) => {
    setIsError(false);
    try {
      const response = await axios.delete(`/list/${id}`);
      console(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      setIsError(true);
      console.log(`Unable to delete: ${error}`);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    /* On load fetch data from the database */
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(initialState);
  }, [initialState]); 

  const appReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'ADD_NEW_LIST':
        return postNewData(action.new_list);
      case 'DELETE_LIST':
        return deleteData(action.list_id);
      default:
        return state;
    }
  };

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(appReducer, initialState);

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch, isError, isLoading }}>
      <div className='App'>
        <Header />
        <Main />
      </div>
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here's the child component inside the main component:

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import AppContext from '../../context/AppContext';

function Listarea() {
  const { state, isError, isLoading, dispatch } = useContext(AppContext);

    console.log(state);
    console.log(isError);
    console.log(isLoading);

  return <div className='list-area'>list area here</div>;
}

export default Listarea;
```

And here's the console.log ouput
[image]

As you can see the data is present in the Parent component but not the child except the other props that is able to get in.

Comment: you send { state } and try to refer to { appState }

Comment: @HagaiHarari sorry that was a typo (i fixed it), i still get the same error. even if i console.log the state before assigning it as a value to the provider it's still and empty array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you update your initialState value it doesn't change state of your useReducer's state.

You can simply use one state and update that state in fetch data, you don't need initialState and state both so you can remove initialState.

```
const appReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'SET_DATA':
        return action.data;
      case 'ADD_NEW_LIST':
        return postNewData(action.new_list);
      case 'DELETE_LIST':
        return deleteData(action.list_id);
      default:
        return state;
    }
  };

const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(appReducer, []);

const fetchData = async () => {
    setIsError(false);
    setIsLoading(true);
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('/list');
      dispatch({ type: 'SET_DATA', data: response.data });
    } catch (error) {
      setIsError(true);
      console.log(`Unable to get: ${error}`);
    }
    setIsLoading(false);
  };
```

Comment: is it allowed to use an empty array and without the reducer parameter in the useReducer function?

Comment: my bad! first argument should be appReducer and and second is empty array